# Convert exponential values in a String into a decimal representation without exponential notation

Tags: java, string, decimal, implicit-conversion, exponential

I have a string build like this :

```
String str = "m -263.61653,-131.25745 c -7.5e-4,-1.04175 0.71025,-1.90875 1.67025,-2.16526"
```

There is **-7.5e-4** that I would like to change into **-0.00075**

I would like to change the exponential value to decimal value to obtain something like this :

```
String str = "m -263.61653,-131.25745 c -0.00075,-1.04175 0.71025,-1.90875 1.67025,-2.16526"
```

I have lots of string like this to check and transform.

I don't really know how to change efficiently the exponential values, because all these values are in a string...

If you know an efficient and fast way to do that, please, tell me.

Comment: try using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

Comment: first try then ask

Comment: Thanks, I asked because I don't know how to do that. Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String patternStr = "[0-9.-]*e[0-9.-]*";
    String word = "m -263.61653,-131.25745 c -7.5e-4,-1.04175 0.71025,-1.90875 1.67025,-2.16526";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        Double d = Double.valueOf(matcher.group());
        System.out.println(word.replaceAll(patternStr, BigDecimal.valueOf(d).toPlainString()));
    }

}
```

Output will be:

```
m -263.61653,-131.25745 c -0.00075,-1.04175 0.71025,-1.90875 1.67025,-2.16526
```

Of course if there are multiple exponentials on the String you will have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Thank you ! It works like a charm. I will adapt it as I have multiple exponentials on the string sometimes. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `toPlainString` in the `BigDecimal` class:

```
String num = "7.5e-4";
new BigDecimal(num).toPlainString();//output 0.00075
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse with Double.parseDouble then format with String.format():

```
    double d = Double.parseDouble("-7.5e-4");
    String s = String.format("%f", d);
```